# How would I parse through a man page to quickly find info about a program option ("-I")?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to build freeglut, I just want to debug a bash script option and I need to find out what specifically `-I` and `-L` gcc compiler options do. I shouldn't have to go through 10,000 freaking lines of text.

I just tried the following

```
man gcc | cat > gcc.txt
grep "-I" gcc.txt
```

Comment: Why not just type `/-l<ret>` in `man`?

Comment: man uses vi like syntax for search. When inside man, type /-L and you will jump to first occurrence of -L. type / <ENTER> next occurrence.

Comment: @UsmanSaleem: `man` does not use `vi`, unless that's how you have your pager set up.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I mean to say "vi like" syntax :)

Comment: And if you want to search backwards, just do `?-l`.  `?` is the backwards version of `/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `--` to denote end of arguments in most Linux tools:

```
man gcc | grep -- -I
```

(and -I and -L are header (include file) and library search directories respectively)

Comment: I chose this as the answer because although all the methods worked (using /-I<ret> worked but you press n to go to the next match, not enter) I like that I don't actually have to enter less to read it.

Answer (score 1):

From the `less(1)` man page:

> ```
>   /pattern
>           Search forward in the file for the N-th line containing the pat‐
>           tern.  N defaults to 1.  The pattern is a regular expression, as
>           recognized by the regular expression library  supplied  by  your
>           system.   The search starts at the first line displayed (but see
>           the -a and -j options, which change this).
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$ man gcc | egrep -A 3 -- '-L|-l'
```

to print 3 lines after (`-A 3`) the match, guessing that the description of the options fits.

Comment: This technically worked but it also spit out a whole bunch of other miscellaneous info where -I was mentioned in passing.